# Homeomorphism between spaces with the complement finite topology

Tags: general-topology

> Describe the homeomorphism between spaces with the complement finite topology $\mathcal{T}_{\text{CF}})$. Do the same with the complement countable topology $\mathcal{T}_{\text{CN}})$

We know that, as $f:X \to X'$ an homeomorphism, it is continuous, open and close, so for each closed set $F$ of $X$ we have that $f(F)$ is closed too, and be closed means to be finite. Unfortunately, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking "Which functions $f : X \to X'$ are homeomorphisms?" ?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I'm asking

Comment: The answer is "The bijections", as shown in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764740/homeomorphism-between-spaces-equipped-with-cofinite-topologies?rq=1